# Insert into Table using JOIN T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I want to insert into a specific column in my table **A** which belongs to **DB 1** 
from my **DB 2** table **B**

In table **A** I have a unique ID field called F6 same goes for table **B** field name F68; both fields are the same they are simply a copy of each other which gives me the opportunity to do a join on them.

So far so good, what I want now is to insert into my table **A** in the field F110 the values from table **B** F64 since I did a join on the "ID's" they should be in the right manner.

All fields are of type VARCHAR.

```
INSERT INTO  [D061_15018659].[dbo].[A](F110)
    SELECT  v.F64,v.F68
FROM [VFM6010061V960P].[dbo].[B] v LEFT JOIN 
    ON v.F68 = F6
```

I have the problem that I have an error on "ON" why so ever I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select query provide 2 columns ==> you need concatenate the columns

You need repeat the tabel **A** in join clause.

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO [D061_15018659].[dbo].[A] (F110)
    SELECT
        v.F64 || v.F68 as theNewF110
    FROM
        [VFM6010061V960P].[dbo].[B] v 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [D061_15018659].[dbo].[A] w ON v.F68 = w.F6
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but  The value can not be inserted in the G column, D061_15018659.dbo.T_A table. The column does not allow NULL values. Error with INSERT.